How to share CKRecord with CKShare properly
When i try to save CKRecord with CKShare  using setModifyRecordsCompletionBlock
NSOperationQueue * quwuw = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
   [quwuw setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
   
   [self createOrFetchZone:^(CKRecordZone *rzone, NSError *error) {
   CKRecordID *recordID = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:recordId zoneID:custZone.zoneID];
   [[self privateCloudDatabase] fetchRecordWithID:recordID completionHandler:^(CKRecord *record, NSError *error) {
       
       if (error) {
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               prephandler(nil, nil,error);
           });
           return;
       }
       
       CKShare * share = [[CKShare alloc] initWithRootRecord:record];
           
           share[CKShareTitleKey] = @"example";
           [share setPublicPermission:CKShareParticipantPermissionReadWrite];
           CKModifyRecordsOperation * op = [[CKModifyRecordsOperation alloc] initWithRecordsToSave:@[share, record] recordIDsToDelete:nil];
           [op setModifyRecordsCompletionBlock:^(NSArray<CKRecord *> * _Nullable savedRecords, NSArray<CKRecordID *> * _Nullable deletedRecordIDs, NSError * _Nullable operationError) {
               if (operationError == nil) {
                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                       prephandler(share, [CKContainer defaultContainer],operationError);
                   });
                   
               }
               else {
                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                       prephandler(share, [CKContainer defaultContainer],operationError);
                   });
               }
           }];
           [op  setDatabase:[self privateCloudDatabase]];
           [quwuw addOperation:op];
   }];
   }];

I got error with userinfo :
CKErrorDescription = "Failed to modify some records";
   CKPartialErrors =     {
       "<CKRecordID: 0x282af5da0; recordName=Share-76902C70-A6CD-4A12-B6DD-6371A1578FBD, zoneID=someCustomZoneName:__defaultOwner__>" = "<CKError 0x28242a670: \"Batch Request Failed\" (22/2024); server message = \"Atomic failure\"; op = 80E158204C153900; uuid = 81B2BAEB-5ADE-447C-A29C-F8D8D174107D; container ID = \"iCloud.com.xxxx.cloudkit-objC\">";
       "<CKRecordID: 0x282af5b20; recordName=0CA7AA50-FCD0-4964-984D-237031BB7106, zoneID=someCustomZoneName:__defaultOwner__>" = "<CKError 0x28242a490: \"Invalid Arguments\" (12/2006); server message = \"Chaining supported for hierarchical sharing only\"; op = 80E158204C153900; uuid = 81B2BAEB-5ADE-447C-A29C-F8D8D174107D; container ID = \"iCloud.com.xxxx.cloudkit-objC\">";
   };
   ContainerID = "iCloud.com.xxxx.cloudkit-objC";
   NSDebugDescription = "CKInternalErrorDomain: 1011";
   NSLocalizedDescription = "Failed to modify some records";
   NSUnderlyingError = "<CKError 0x28242a2e0: \"Partial Failure\" (1011); \"Failed to modify some records\"; partial errors: {\n\t0CA7AA50-FCD0-4964-984D-237031BB7106:(someCustomZoneName:__defaultOwner__) = <CKError 0x28242a490: \"Invalid Arguments\" (12/2006); server message = \"Chaining supported for hierarchical sharing only\"; op = 80E158204C153900; uuid = 81B2BAEB-5ADE-447C-A29C-F8D8D174107D>\n\t... 1 \"Batch Request Failed\" CKError's omited ...\n}>";
   RequestUUID = "81B2BAEB-5ADE-447C-A29C-F8D8D174107D";

My record has no parent. Is it possible to share only one CKRecord without set parent reference?

Fun fact: when I copy all the necessary code to a newly created project, errors disappear.
